# useless mechanism of javascript?

Tags: javascript

scope a.pass belongs to? i mean what is the point of being able to set a variable outside the function like a.pass and not be able to call that in the function?

```
function a(){
   var name ="Euler Henrique";
   var age =32;

   return pass;
}


a.pass ="12q3";


alert(a());
```

that gives: ReferenceError: pass is not defined

Comment: You're adding value to a function not define variable. To access pass from inside a function you need to use the same `return a.pass;`

Comment: `a.pass` is a property of the function object, it's not a variable inside the function - it's not a variable at all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the object for the access (the function `a` actually).

```js
function a() {
  var name = "Euler Henrique";
  var age = 32;

  return a.pass;
}


a.pass = "12q3";


console.log(a());
```

Comment: Why not `this.pass`?

Comment: @connexo — Because `this` doesn't have a value (unless you aren't running in strict mode, in which case it is whatever the default object is for the JS environment and not `a`)

Comment: Well, it doesn't make much sense the way it is written anyway. So if you did `let b = new a()` and then `console.log(b());` ? That would invoke the constructor which would set the proper context.